# Como posso melhorar a segurança do meu sistema de manter o usuário conectado?

Tags: php

Partindo da ideia de que o usuário digitou o login e senha corretamente na página de login, irei salvar um cookie para autenticar o usuário para que o login permaneça ativo e o usuário consiga se conectar a outros dispositivos sem ser deslogado na sessão anterior.

**Para isso comecei criando uma tabela no banco de dados com as seguintes características:**

```
CREATE TABLE `manter_login` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `login_history` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`login_history`))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `manter_login`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `id_user` (`id_user`);

ALTER TABLE `manter_login`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
COMMIT;
```

**E criando as seguintes funções:**

```
define("USER2", 'root');
define("PASS2", '');
define("NAME2", 'users');

//conexão area de login
try {
    $db2 = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".NAME2.";charset=utf8", "".USER2."", "".PASS2."");
    $db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch (PDOException $e2) {
    echo $e2->getMessage();
}

// Função basica para gerenciamento PDO
function sql2($db2, $q, $params, $return) {
  // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $db2->prepare($q);
  // Execute statement
    $stmt->execute($params);
  // Decida se deseja retornar as linhas ou apenas contar as linhas
    if ($return == "rows") {
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }elseif ($return == "rowsall") {
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }elseif ($return == "count") {
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }elseif( $return == "lastid"){
        return $db2->lastInsertId();
    }elseif( $return == "fake"){
        //fake sem nada
    }
}

function salvarDadosLoginCookie($user_id, $removeSeletorLogin = 0){
    global $db2;

    $contar_registros = sql2($db2, "SELECT id FROM manter_login WHERE id_user = ?", array($user_id), "count");
    $pega_ip = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
    $seletor = base64_encode(random_bytes(9));
    $autenticador = random_bytes(33);
    $meu_token = $seletor.':'.base64_encode($autenticador);
    
    //Array com as informações do usuario para podermos autenticar mais tarde
    $novoArray = [
        'ip' => $pega_ip,
        'seletor' => $seletor,
        'autenticador' => hash('sha256', $autenticador),
        'data' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time())
    ];
    
    //Se a variavel removeSeletorLogin for diferente de zero, e porque a função foi chamada apos validar o hash_equals, então precisamos dar update no array e remover o seletor, para que não possa ser mais usado
    if($removeSeletorLogin !== 0){
        $lrdados = sql2($db2, "SELECT * FROM manter_login WHERE id_user = ?", array($user_id), "rows");
        $gerarNovoArrayRemovendoSeletor = removeArrayLogin($removeSeletorLogin, $lrdados['login_history']);

        sql2($db2, "UPDATE manter_login SET login_history = ? WHERE id_user = ?", array($gerarNovoArrayRemovendoSeletor, $user_id), "fake");
    }
    
    //Se não houver registros iremos inserir um novo com o array de informações, Se ja exister um registro, o mesmo será modificado e iremos acrescentar um novo indice de array a ele, Esse Array poderá ter ate 5 indices, ou seja iremos permitir o uso da conta de um usuario a 5 dispostivos
    if($contar_registros > 0){
        $ldados = sql2($db2, "SELECT * FROM manter_login WHERE id_user = ?", array($user_id), "rows");
        $gerarNovoArray = updateArrayLogin($ldados['login_history'], $novoArray);
        
        //Inciaremos esse session para poder fazer logout desse seletor mais tarde
        $_SESSION['seletor_login_atual'] = $seletor;
        
        sql2($db2, "UPDATE manter_login SET login_history = ? WHERE id_user = ?", array($gerarNovoArray, $user_id), "fake");
    }else{
        //Array Inicial
        $novoArrayInsert = array($novoArray);
        sql2($db2, "INSERT INTO manter_login(id_user, login_history) VALUES (?, ?)", array($user_id, json_encode($novoArrayInsert)), "fake");
    }
    
    // Cookie com token e id do usuario, esse id será usado para validar se existe um seletor para um usuario, se houver um seletor pra ele, iremos permitir o login, se não houver o login e recusado
    setcookie('user_valid', json_encode(array( 'user_id' => $user_id, 'token' => $meu_token)), time() + (86400 * 7), '/', null, true, true);
}

function autenticarLogin(){
    global $db2;

    // Verificamos se o cookie existe
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['user_valid']) || empty($_COOKIE['user_valid'])) {
        return false;
    }

    // Verificamos se o cookie e valido
    if(!$cookie_login = @json_decode($_COOKIE['user_valid'], true)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Verificamos se os parametros estão corretos
    if (!(isset($cookie_login['user_id']) || isset($cookie_login['token']))) {
        return false;
    }

    // Verificamos o tamanho do cookie 
    if(strlen($_COOKIE['user_valid']) > 1500){
        return false;
    }
    
    // Verificamos se o separador existe
    if ((strpos($cookie_login['token'], ':') !== false) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    
    $id_user_by_cookie = abs($cookie_login['user_id']);

    // Verificamos se existe algum registro com o id do usuario no banco de dados
    $contar_registros_user = sql2($db2, "SELECT * FROM manter_login WHERE id_user = ?", array($id_user_by_cookie), "count");

    if($contar_registros_user === 0){
        return false;
    }

    if (empty($_SESSION['user_logado_id']) && !empty($_COOKIE['user_valid'])) {
        list($seletor, $autenticador) = explode(':', $cookie_login['token']);
        
        $registro_atual = sql2($db2, "SELECT * FROM manter_login WHERE id_user = ?", array($id_user_by_cookie), "rows");
        $encoda_login_history = json_decode($registro_atual['login_history'], true);

        // definido inicialmente como 0, se no foreach houver um seletor igual ao cookie, iremos definir o valor pra 1
        $verifica_existencia_seletor = 0; 
        $captura_autenticador = '';
        $captura_ip = '';
        $captura_seletor = '';
        
        //Vamos descobrir se os seletores do usuario pesquisado e igual ao que está no cookie
        foreach($encoda_login_history as $hlogin => $data) {
            if($data['seletor'] == $seletor){
                //Seletor Foi encontrado então iremos alterar o valor pra 1
                $verifica_existencia_seletor = 1;
                //Passamos o valor do token autenticador pra variavel
                $captura_autenticador = $data['autenticador'];
                //Passamos o ip para uma variavel externa para podermos validar tbm
                $captura_ip = $data['ip'];
                //Pegamos o seletor
                $captura_seletor = $data['seletor'];
                
                //vou limitar a vida de um cookie a 7 dias, ja que geramos um novo sempre que o session leva update
                if(calculaDiferencaData($data['data']) >= 7){
                    //Removemos o Indice do array que tem o seletor gerado a mais de 7 dias
                    sql2($db2, "UPDATE manter_login SET login_history = ? WHERE id_user = ?", array(removeArrayLogin($seletor, $registro_atual['login_history']), $registro_atual['id_user']), "fake");

                    //Nesse caso o seletor deixou de existir, então voltaremos o valor dele para zero
                    $verifica_existencia_seletor = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        //Verificamos se o seletor foi encontrado
        if($verifica_existencia_seletor === 0){
            setcookie('user_valid', null);
            return false;
        }

        $pega_ip = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
        
        //Se os ips do banco de dados e o ip da maquina do usuario forem diferentes não iniciaremos a sessao de login
        if($captura_ip !== $pega_ip){
            return false;
        }

        //Validamos o hash - se estiver tudo ok, podemos iniciar a session
        if (hash_equals($captura_autenticador, hash('sha256', base64_decode($autenticador)))) {
            //Inciaremos a session com id do usuario
            $_SESSION['user_logado_id'] = $registro_atual['id_user'];
            
            //Agora que o login foi bem sucessido, iremos re-criar o cookie e deletar o seletor do array, para que ele não possa ser utilizado novamente
            salvarDadosLoginCookie($registro_atual['id_user'], $captura_seletor);

            return true;
        }
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_logado_id'])){
        return true;
    }
}

//Função destinada para deslogar o dispositivo que o usuario ta logado
function deslogarDispositivoAtual(){
    global $ta_logado, $db2;
    
    if($ta_logado === 1){
        $contar_registros_logout = sql2($db2, "SELECT * FROM manter_login WHERE id_user = ?", array($_SESSION['user_logado_id']), "count");
        
        if($contar_registros_logout > 0){
            $registros_logout = sql2($db2, "SELECT * FROM manter_login WHERE id_user = ?", array($_SESSION['user_logado_id']), "rows");

            sql2($db2, "UPDATE manter_login SET login_history = ? WHERE id_user = ?", array(removeArrayLogin($_SESSION['seletor_login_atual'], $registros_logout['login_history']), $_SESSION['user_logado_id']), "fake");
        }
    }
    
    session_destroy();
    setcookie('user_valid', null);
}

//Função para usar quando o usuario mudar a senha
function deslogarDeTodosDispositivos($id_deslogar){
    global $db2;
    
    sql2($db2, "DELETE FROM manter_login WHERE id_user = ?", array($id_deslogar), "fake");
    
    session_destroy();
    setcookie('user_valid', null);
}

function calculaDiferencaData($DataEvento){
    $hoje = new DateTime();
    $diferenca = $hoje->diff(new DateTime($DataEvento));
    return $diferenca->days;
}

function updateArrayLogin($arrayAtual, $novoArray){
    
    $arrayAtual = json_decode($arrayAtual, true);
    
    if(!is_array($arrayAtual)){
        $arrayAtual = array();
    }
    
    $arrayAtual[] = $novoArray;
    
    $arrayNovo = array_filter($arrayAtual, function($value) {
        return is_array($value);
    });

    if(($quantidade = count($arrayNovo)) > 5){
        $arrayNovo = array_slice($arrayNovo, $quantidade - 5, 5);
    }
    
    return json_encode($arrayNovo);
}

function removeArrayLogin($seletor, $arrayEdit){
    
    $arrayEdit = json_decode($arrayEdit, true);

    if(!is_array($arrayEdit)){
        $arrayEdit = array();
    }
    
    foreach($arrayEdit as $arrayE => $data) {
        if($data['seletor'] == $seletor){
            unset($arrayEdit[$arrayE]);
        }
    }
    
    return json_encode($arrayEdit);
}
```

**e por fim iniciando as funções para verificar se o usuário está logado**

```
$ta_logado = 0;

//Se o session user_logado_id não existe, iremos verificar se uma possivel sessão pode ser iniciada
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_logado_id']) || empty($_SESSION['user_logado_id'])){
    autenticarLogin();
}
//Se ja existir user_logado_id, iremos chamar os dados no banco de dados
if(isset($_SESSION['user_logado_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_logado_id'])){
    
    //Porem antes vamos validar e ver se o usuario não mudou a senha. Pois quando o usuario mudar a senha o registro no banco de dados e deletado.
    $contar_registros_user_atual = sql2($db2, "SELECT * FROM manter_login WHERE id_user = ?", array($_SESSION['user_logado_id']), "count");
    
    if($contar_registros_user_atual === 0){
        session_destroy();
        setcookie('user_valid', null);
    }else{
        $verificaDados = sql2($db2, "SELECT * from usuarios WHERE id = ?", array($_SESSION['user_logado_id']), "rows");
        if(isset($verificaDados['usuario']) && !empty($verificaDados['usuario'])) {
            $ta_logado = 1;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Como posso melhorar a segurança do meu sistema?

Answer (score 0):

Não há como melhorar a segurança de um sistema sem assumir quais seriam os problemas. Você precisa definir quais seriam os problemas, para então conseguir definir o que fazer para cada uma das situações (e quais novos problemas isso criaria).

---

Mas, em geral, existe alguns pontos:

**A validação de IP:**

Tenha certeza de que está negando qualquer ao site/servidor por fora do CloudFlare. Caso contrário, se você permitir que acesse a página por fora do CloudFlare (isso é, `http://123.123.123.123/sua-pagina.php`) seria possível o cabeçalho de `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP`.

- Em geral, restringir o IP desta forma também implica um problema de usabilidade, já que quem utiliza dados moveis pode constantemente ter o IP alterado. Além disso vários usuários podem usar o mesmo IP, devido ao CGNAT e ao compartilhamento de rede.

**Acesso a escrita/atualização no banco de dados:**

Você está usando `hash` ao invés de `hmac`, isso faz com que o banco de dados tenha a `hash` e o usuário a `pre-imagem da hash`. Porém, isso não é suficiente se atacante tiver acesso de escrita (ou atualização) do banco de dados.

- Acredito que uma melhor construção seria algo como: `hmac('sha256', $_CHAVE_DA_APLICAO, $_ID_DO_USARIO + $_TOKEN_ALEATORIO)`. Essa construção impede duas variantes de ataque, que atualmente a `hash` não protege:

  - Se for possível criar um registro em `manter_login` de maneira arbitraria: o token terá que usar o `$_CHAVE_DA_APLICAO`, o que será desconhecido para o atacante (assumindo que a `$_CHAVE_DA_APLICAO` esteja segura até esse ponto).
  - Se for possível atualizar e ver os dados de `manter_login`, a concatenação de `$_ID_DO_USARIO + $_TOKEN_ALEATORIO` impossibilitará o re-uso de uma pré-imagem conhecida. Isso é mais difícil de explicar: suponha que eu tenha uma conta, e tenho o TOKEN=A corresponde a HASH=B e dá acesso ao ID=100. Eu poderia alterar o ID do usuário vinculado ao HASH=B, assim o meu TOKEN=A teria acesso à outra conta (ID=111). A concatenação invalida esse ataque, já que pré-imagem é construída baseada o ID do usuário, portanto atualizar o ID no banco de dados será inútil. Então mesmo que eu altere o banco de dados para ID=111, o `hmac` será de `100 + token` e então será inválido para `111 + token`.

**$O `$seletor` não é usado no SELECT**

Não sei qual o proposito do `$selector`, mas inicialmente achei que isso fosse para intencionalmente gerar colisões, mas aparentemente não é o caso.

- Acredito que o `$selector` poderia ser usado no `SELECT`, afim de gerar maiores colisões.

  - Essa construção dificulta saber se um usuário esteve logado recentemente, ou se há muitos ou poucos acessos, baseado no tempo de resposta (timing-attack). Isso ocorre porque vários tokens, de vários usuários distintos, poderiam usar o mesmo `$selector`.
  - Essa solução também pode acabar tendo um DoS, uma vez que devido a quantidade de colisões poderia conter muitos registros.

---

Talvez existam mais problemas, ou os problemas mencionados aqui sejam ignoráveis. Como disse no inicio, isso depende de qual problema você realmente quer resolver e do que considera como um problema. Por exemplo, em alguns casos pode assumir que: se o banco de dados está comprometido ao ponto de permitir adicionar sessões, o mesmo banco de dados também está comprometido ao ponto de permitir alterar a senha de um usuário arbitrariamente.

Comment: Mudei pra hmac e coloquei uma CHAVE_DA_APLICAO direto no array "$novoArray", pq dessa forma cada sessão vai ter um CHAVE_DA_APLICAO própria